# How to create DynamoDB table using docker CMD instruction and the AWS CLI inside running container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-dynamodb

Hello have a simple Dockerfile which has to create the DynamoDB tables:

```
FROM amazon/aws-cli AS seed                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                       
CMD \                                                                                                                                                  
aws dynamodb --endpoint-url http://localhost:8080 create-table \                                                                                       
    --table-name mytable \                                                                                                           
    --attribute-definitions AttributeName=user_id,AttributeType=N AttributeName=order_id,AttributeType=N \
    --key-schema AttributeName=user_id,KeyType=HASH AttributeName=order_id,KeyType=RANGE \                                                             
    --provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=5,WriteCapacityUnits=5 \                                                                                
    --region eu-west-2
```

When I'm trying to run it I get the following output:

```
Attaching to my-container
my-container       | 
my-container       | usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
my-container       | To see help text, you can run:
my-container       | 
my-container       |   aws help
my-container       |   aws <command> help
my-container       |   aws <command> <subcommand> help
my-container       | 
my-container       | aws: error: argument command: Invalid choice, valid choices are:
my-container       | 
my-container       | accessanalyzer                           | account                                 
my-container       | acm                                      | acm-pca                                 
my-container       | alexaforbusiness                         | amp                                     
my-container       | amplify                                  | amplifybackend                          
my-container       | amplifyuibuilder                         | apigateway                              
my-container       | apigatewaymanagementapi                  | apigatewayv2                            

// Lot of services in here
                       
my-container       | s3                                       | ddb                                     
my-container       | configure                                | deploy                                  
my-container       | configservice                            | opsworks-cm                             
my-container       | history                                  | cli-dev                                 
my-container       | help                                    
my-container       | 
my-container exited with code 252
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this particular image, the `CMD` must be in JSON-array syntax (one shell word to an array element) and must not contain the `aws` command.

```sh
FROM amazon/aws-cli
CMD ["dynamodb", "create-table", "..."]
```

This is because [the aws-cli image declares `ENTRYPOINT ["aws"]`](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/v2/docker/Dockerfile#L21), [the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` are combined into a single command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact), and [string-format `CMD` inserts a shell wrapper](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd).  Your main container command in the current form is something like `aws sh -c 'aws dynamodb ...'` which the tool doesn't really understand.

(I might run this particular command as a standalone `docker run` command and not try to package it into an image, or possibly use the AWS SDK as part of your integration-test setup code.  The explicit `localhost` endpoint also seems like it might not work well, since that will usually refer to the same container that's only running the AWS CLI.)

Answer (score 0):

In your command you must **not have a space after** \  that why maybe you recevie the error because the rest statements is ignored.

Try test again  with this :

```
aws dynamodb --endpoint-url http://localhost:8080 create-table \
--table-name mytable \
--attribute-definitions AttributeName=user_id,AttributeType=N AttributeName=order_id,AttributeType=N \
--key-schema AttributeName=user_id,KeyType=HASH AttributeName=order_id,KeyType=RANGE \
--provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=5,WriteCapacityUnits=5 \
--region eu-west-2
```

And also try to have a fake profile, because its need an access key and a secret key even if its locally

Comment: Hello @Hatim, thanks for the interest, I've removed the preceding spaces but the output is still the same :/

Comment: Okay @Bulchsu, I was not focus on the CMD part, indeed, the correct answer is to split in the command part in dockerfile